# SVG outer alignment of semi transparent stroke

Tags: html, svg

I am using an SVG image in my project. The border is currently centered and very much noticeable because of the lower opacity. Is there any way to show the border only outside the fill area? CSS property stroke-alignment is not working.

This isn't a duplicate as it's a particular problem with a semi transparent border.

[image]

Here is the SVG code:

```
<svg style="left: 50px; top: 261px; z-index: 16; width: 145px; height: 198px;
  transform: rotate(0deg);" version="1.1" id="Layer_16"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-0.9 -1 41.9 41.9" xml:space="preserve"
>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad_16" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#5fe034; stop-opacity:1"></stop
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#ed2bb6; stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <polygon style="fill:url(#grad_16); stroke: #59e38e; stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.4" stroke-alignment="outer"
    points="30.8,11.3 20,0.5 9.3,11.4 14.6,11.4 14.7,28.7 9.2,28.7 20,39.5 30.8,28.6 25.4,28.6 25.3,11.3"
   ></polygon>
</svg>
```

Thanks and Regards,

Neha

Comment: what if you share the SVG ?

Comment: Added the SVG code

Comment: I don't think is is "an exact duplicate" of the suggested question. You can e.g. clone your polygon element and apply the transparent border only to the underlying one. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/devmount/9e4gkz1c/

Comment: But if I reduce the opacity of the fill, it causes the same issue,  https://jsfiddle.net/9e4gkz1c/9/

Comment: Ok in this case, you can simply set a general opacity for the whole `<svg>` element. See my updated fiddle above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but this wont work separately for the two different gradients right ?